# Why my cards are not randomly placed?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a memory card game. Each time when I refresh the page, the cards are supposed to place in a random position but it turns out that they remain in the same position.

here is the code :

```
var cardsArray = [{
'name': 'ball',
'img': '../img/ball.png',
},
{
'name': 'building',
'img': '../img/building.png',
},
{
'name': 'fan',
'img': '../img/fan.png',
},
{ 
'name': 'fish',
'img': '../img/fish.png',
},
{
'name': 'fishball',
'img': '../img/fishball.png',
},
{
'name': 'flower',
'img': '../img/flower.png',
},
{
'name': 'hill',
'img': '../img/hill.png',
},
{
'name': 'orange',
'img': '../img/orange.png',
},
{
'name': 'boo',
'img': '../img/boo.png',
},
{
'name': 'shoe',
'img': '../img/shoe.png',
},
];



var firstGuess = '';
var secondGuess = '';
var count = 0;
var previousTarget = null;
var delay = 1200;
var moves;
var matched;
var score;

var game = document.getElementById('game');
var grid = document.createElement('section');

const gameGrid = cardsArray
.concat(cardsArray)
.sort(function() {
0.5 - Math.random()
});


function startGame() {
grid.setAttribute('class', 'grid');
game.appendChild(grid);

moves = 0;
score = 0;
matched = 0;
document.getElementById("moves").innerHTML = moves;
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;

gameGrid.forEach(function(item) {
  const {
  name,
  img
} = item;

const card = document.createElement('div');
card.classList.add('card');
card.dataset.name = name;

const front = document.createElement('div');
front.classList.add('front');

const back = document.createElement('div');
back.classList.add('back');
back.style.backgroundImage = `url(${img})`;

grid.appendChild(card);
card.appendChild(front);
card.appendChild(back);
});

}
```

Sorry, I know it might be a bit long, but I guess the problem might be here:

```
const gameGrid = cardsArray
.concat(cardsArray)
.sort(function() {
0.5 - Math.random()
});
```

Did I do something wrong here? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually returning the random value to sort on.

```
const gameGrid = cardsArray
.concat(cardsArray)
.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random()
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure that will be a biased sorting function. Better to assign values to each element and sort by those values instead.

Comment: Note that [if the sort callback isn't consistent the sort is implementation-defined](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.sort). A valid JavaScript implementation could do anything like leave the array in its original order or simply reverse it every time you call it with an inconsistent callback. In all common implementations you will probably get what @CertainPerformance says, a biased ordering that appears somewhat random. I doubt you'll find any implementation give you a uniform distribution of all possible orderings; use Fisher-Yates for that.